# Placeholder change based on the selection in a form

Tags: angular, forms

I want to change the placeholder based on the selection.

//div with the two-option toggle

```
  <div fd-form-item>
    <label fd-form-label for="select-targetType">Showroom type:</label>
    <select class="fd-form-select" id="select-targetType" formControlName="targetType">
      <option *ngFor="let targetType of targetTypes" [ngValue]="targetType">{{ targetType }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <br />
```

//div with a space for placeholder - it should display two options e.g. test1.com and e.g. test2.com

```
  <div fd-form-item *ngIf="targetType.value != null">
    <label fd-form-label for="input-showroom-hostname" [required]="true">URL:</label>
    <fd-form-input-message-group>
      <input
        fd-form-control
        type="text"
        id="input-showroom-hostname"
        placeholder="e.g. test1.com"
        formControlName="hostname"
        [state]="determineFormControlState(hostname)"
        (keydown.enter)="addShowroom()"
      />
      <fd-form-message *ngIf="hasRequiredErrors(hostname)" [type]="'error'"> {{ REQUIRED }} </fd-form-message>
      <fd-form-message *ngIf="hasShowroomUserRightsErrors(hostname)" [type]="'error'"> {{ SHOWROOM_USER_RIGHTS }}</fd-form-message>
      <fd-form-message *ngIf="hasPatternErrors(hostname)" [type]="'error'"> {{ URL_PATTERN }} </fd-form-message>
    </fd-form-input-message-group>
  </div>
  <br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you are using reactive forms you can subscribe to the changes in the form and modify a variable in your TS file. This in turn can be bound to the placeholder - something like this.

```
placeholder: string;

this.form.get('targetType').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
     if(val === 'x') {
         this.placeholder = 'test1.com'
     }
     if(val === 'y') {
         this.placeholder = 'test2.com'
     }
})
```

Then for your input

`[placeholder]="placeholder"`

You will need to unsubscribe from this when you destroy the component.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [placeholder]="custom-variable?custom-variable:'default placeholde'" in your html code and bind value to your variable